# How to properly insert JavaScript subreport to Java main report on JasperReports 3.5?

Tags: javascript, jasper-reports, rhino, subreport

Using iReport and JasperReport 3.5 (legacy, not my choice)
I have main blank report in Java and trying to insert also blank subreport with report language = JavaScript.

Both have just "select 1 as Field1 from dual" queries and one *label* component.

In result JasperReports throws an error with following stack (There is no "new java.lang.Integer(1)" in report code)

> Error filling print... net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : 
>       **Source text : new java.lang.Integer(1)**  net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : 
>       Source text : new java.lang.Integer(1)  Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: **Error evaluating expression : 
>       Source text : new java.lang.Integer(1)**  bla-bla-bla Caused by: **java.lang.RuntimeException: No Context associated with current Thread**
>   at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.getContext(Context.java:2206) 
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.SecurityController.createLoader(SecurityController.java:136) 
>       at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.Codegen.defineClass(Codegen.java:143)

What's wrong?

Found [something with Birt](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/61315/), but don't know how to make this in JasperReports

> Javascript context has to be iniatilized for each  individual thread
>   as shown below, then running print task from worker thread  works.

```
org.mozilla.javascript.Context.enter();
<BIRT print task...>
org.mozilla.javascript.Context.exit();
```

UPDATE
Seems this report appears when  properties have  in it.

And then I changed subreport language to "java" then the error disappears.

Main report is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report0" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[select 123123 as DFG from dual]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="DFG" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <title>
        <band height="79">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[MAIN]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="20" width="555" height="59"/>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["subReport1.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

Sub report is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1" language="javascript" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select 155554444445554 as Hy from dual]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="HY" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="87" y="29" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Hello from subreport]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="70">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="63" y="14" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.math.BigDecimal"><![CDATA[$F{HY}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: If you solved the issue - it is better to post the solution as the answer

Comment: Nope, I can't realize what is a reason for the problem :( To change the language to 'Java' eliminates the error, but I need to use 'javascript' in subreport cause don'n know Java.